# How can I instantiate template of multiple enums concisely?

Tags: c++, templates

If I want to instantiate all combinations of Type1, Type2 and Type3 for template function `Caclculate`, it seems that I have to code 72 lines. Is there any way to simplify these code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

enum Type1 {
    kType1_1,
    kType1_2,
    kType1_3,
    kType1_4,
    kType1_5,
    kType1_6,
};

enum Type2 {
    kType2_1,
    kType2_2,
    kType2_3,
};

enum Type3 {
    kType3_1,
    kType3_2,
    kType3_3,
    kType3_4,
};

template <Type1 t1, Type2 t2, Type3 t3>
int Caclculate() {
    std::cout << static_cast<int32_t>(t1) << " " << static_cast<int32_t>(t2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int CalculateHandler(Type1 t1, Type2 t2, Type3 t3) {
    static std::map<std::tuple<Type1, Type2, Type3>, std::function<int()>> func = {
        std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(Type1::kType1_1, Type2::kType2_1, Type3::kType3_1), Caclculate<Type1::kType1_1, Type2::kType2_1, Type3::kType3_1>),
        std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(Type1::kType1_1, Type2::kType2_2, Type3::kType3_1), Caclculate<Type1::kType1_1, Type2::kType2_2, Type3::kType3_1>),
    };
    return func[std::make_tuple(t1, t2, t3)]();
}

int main() {
    CalculateHandler(kType1_1, kType2_2, kType3_1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but the general solution might be longer than just typing it out.

We want to plug the enums into template arguments and get a list of combinations out:

```cpp
using Input1 = Sequence<Type1_1, Type1_2>;
using Input2 = Sequence<Type2_1, Type2_2>;
using Input3 = Sequence<Type3_1, Type3_2>;

using Output = Combine<Input1, Input2, Input3>;
/* result: CombinationSet<
    Combination<Type1_1, Type2_1, Type3_1>,
    Combination<Type1_1, Type2_1, Type3_2>,
    Combination<Type1_1, Type2_2, Type3_1>,
    // etc
*/
```

So, first, define the input and output types:

```cpp
template <typename T, T... Cs>
struct Sequence {
    using Type = T; //
};

// represents one iteration of Combined lists
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct Combination;

// a set of Combinations
template <typename... Ts>
struct CombinationSet;
```

Now, it's possible to define the first level: turn two constants and a sequence into a set of combinations. We can deduce the types of the constant and sequence through partial specialization:

```cpp
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct CombineImpl;

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, T1 C1, T2 C2, T3... C3s>
struct CombineImpl<std::integral_constant<T1, C1>, std::integral_constant<T2, C2>, Sequence<T3, C3s...>>
{
    using Type = CombinationSet<Combination<std::integral_constant<T1, C1>, std::integral_constant<T2, C2>, std::integral_constant<T3, C3s>>...>;
};

/* example: 
       CombineImpl<
           std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
           std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
           Sequence<Type3, Type3_1, Type3_2>
       >
   gets turned into:
       CombinationSet<
           Combination<
               std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>
           >,
           Combination<
               std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_2>
           >
       >
*/
```

Now the next level: if we have a constant and two sequences, we can call `CombineImpl<C, C, S>` multiple times and get a bunch of `CombinationSet`s. BUT, we need a way to concatenate all the sets:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, T1 I1, T2... I2s, T3... I3s>
struct CombineImpl<std::integral_constant<T1, I1>, Sequence<T2, I2s...>, Sequence<T3, I3s...>> 
{
    using Type = Merge<typename CombineImpl<std::integral_constant<T1, I1>, std::integral_constant<T2, I2s>, Sequence<T3, I3s...>>::Type...>;
              // ^^^^^ how to implement this?
};
```

I can only think of using a recursive type to flatten the sets. There's probably a better `log n` solution but I'm not smart enough to make it:

```cpp
// stub - the first type is the output set, followed by input sets
template <typename... Ts>
struct MergeImpl;

// recursive bit - deduce the combinations in the next set, add to output
template <typename... TOut, typename... Ts, typename... TIn>
struct MergeImpl<CombinationSet<TOut...>, CombinationSet<Ts...>, TIn...> 
{
    using Type = typename MergeImpl<CombinationSet<TOut..., Ts...>, TIn...>::Type;
};

// terminal - when there are no more inputs, expose the output.
template <typename... TOut>
struct MergeImpl<CombinationSet<TOut...>>
{
    using Type = CombinationSet<TOut...>;
};

// type alias to start with an empty output set
template <typename... Ts>
using Merge = typename MergeImpl<CombinationSet<>, Ts...>::Type;

/* example: 
       Merge<
           CombinationSet<
               Combination<
                   std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>
               >,
               Combination<
                   std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_2>
               >
           >,
           CombinationSet<
               Combination<
                   std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_2>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>
               >
           >
        >
    Gets turned into:
        CombinationSet<
           Combination<
               std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>
           >,
           Combination<
               std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_1>,
               std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_2>
               >
           Combination<
               std::integral_constant<Type1, Type1_1>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type2_2>,
                   std::integral_constant<Type2, Type4_1>
               >
        >
```

Now with merge defined, we can just add another layer to get all the combinations for three sequences:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, T1... I1s, T2... I2s, T3... I3s>
struct CombineImpl<Sequence<T1, I1s...>, Sequence<T2, I2s...>, Sequence<T3, I3s...>>
{
    using Type = Merge<typename CombineImpl<std::integral_constant<T1, I1s>, Sequence<T2, I2s...>, Sequence<T3, I3s...>>::Type...>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
using Combine = typename CombineImpl<T1, T2, T3>::Type;
```

The next step is to create the map from a `CombinationSet`. I'm going to use partial specialization again:

```cpp
// stub
template <typename>
struct CalculateHandlerImpl;

// specialization - deduce combination types and declare static map
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, T1... C1s, T2... C2s, T3... C3s>
struct CalculateHandlerImpl<CombinationSet<Combination<std::integral_constant<T1, C1s>, std::integral_constant<T2, C2s>, std::integral_constant<T3, C3s>>...>> {
    static std::map<std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>, std::function<int()>> value;
};

// static maps have to be defined out of line
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, T1... C1s, T2... C2s, T3... C3s>
std::map<std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>, std::function<int()>> CalculateHandlerImpl<CombinationSet<Combination<std::integral_constant<T1, C1s>, std::integral_constant<T2, C2s>, std::integral_constant<T3, C3s>>...>>::value = {
    { std::make_tuple(C1s, C2s, C3s), Calculate<C1s, C2s, C3s> }...
};
```

Finally, write a handler function to tie it all together:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
int CalculateHandler(typename T1::Type t1, typename T2::Type t2, typename T3::Type t3) {
    return CalculateHandlerImpl<Combine<T1, T2, T3>>::value[std::make_tuple(t1, t2, t3)]();
}

// maybe a variadic macro can help define this and the enum at the same time
using Type1Seq = Sequence<Type1, 
    kType1_1, 
    kType1_2, 
    kType1_3, 
    kType1_4, 
    kType1_5, 
    kType1_6>;

using Type2Seq = Sequence<
    Type2, 
    kType2_1, 
    kType2_2, 
    kType2_3>;

using Type3Seq = Sequence<Type3,
    kType3_1,
    kType3_2,
    kType3_3,
    kType3_4>;

int main() {
    CalculateHandler<Type1Seq, Type2Seq, Type3Seq>(kType1_1, kType2_2, kType3_1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WPaPqa4zT

Now, you'll notice that there is probably at least 72 lines for all this template code. Plus, it will *definitely* increase compilation time. But the above would help if the lists grow. And it could save you the trouble of checking that you included all the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

use for(int i;...)
then, use every <> for every single time to have a new variable. then your code will be so much shorter.
note: you have to use <> in for{}; otherwise it won't work.
contact me if you need more clarification about it.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
`func[std::make_tuple(static_cast<Type1>(i), static_cast<Type2>(j), static_cast<Type3>(k))] = Caclculate<static_cast<Type1>(i), static_cast<Type2>(j), static_cast<Type3>(k)>();`
But it seems impossible to get compiled.
`error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression Caclculate<static_cast<Type1>(i), static_cast<Type2>(j), static_cast<Type3>(k)>();`